# How do I send a wstring variable over a socket?

Tags: c++, sockets

I have to send information between a client and a server in C++. I have found that the following code allows me to send integers over the connection.

Server:

```
int number = 5;
send(clientSocket, (char*)&number, sizeof(number), 0); //Integer is sent to client
```

Client:

```
int number;
recv(serverSocket, (char*)&number, sizeof(number), 0); //Integer is received and assigned to 'number'
```

However, I am now trying to send a wstring variable using the exact same code (replace 'int' with 'wstring') and it fails to send the value correctly. How can I send a wstring over the socket and receive it on the client?

Comment: What exactly is meant by `fails to send the value correctly`? Can you show inputs and outputs or whatever errors you get?

Comment: Your integer code only works by luck. For example, what happens if the `recv` reads fewer bytes than were sent? What happens if the server and client represent integers using different numbers of bytes?

Comment: You serialize the variable according to whatever metaformat you chose. Seriously, search the term "serialization" on the net. Just dumping the bytes representing (parts of) your string in memory isn't going to work. It only works for really primitive type and that only some of the time.

Comment: *it fails to send the value correctly*  -- It didn't fail.  The code is doing exactly as written.  You pointed to an object and from there,  sent sizeof(wstring) raw bytes over the socket.  The issue is that you were not aware of what you were sending, and thus believed that `send` and `recv` knows what the object represents.

Comment: In addition, you should have been suspicious of something, knowing that `sizeof(wstring)` is a compile-time constant and *never* changes value, whether the string is 1 character or a million characters.  So right there should have been the tip-off that this isn't going to work.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1:
Sender and receiver agree on a shared character encoding. If you are writing both sender and receiver, this is easy. Pick one. Preferably pick one with a good C++ support library on both the sending and receiving platforms. UTF-8 generally has good support.

Step 2:
Sender and receiver agree on how you will signal the end of a string. Common choices are read until NULL and sending the length of the string before you send the string. Some times you want to send the length of the encoded string in bytes to make reading and buffering the encoded string easier.

Step 3:
Sender encodes the string using the agreed upon encoding into a `char` buffer. This is, unfortunately, messier in C++ than it should be. You may find yourself going back to step 1 and re-choosing the encoding because the encoding you chose doesn't have as good library support as you thought.

Step 4 A:
Write the buffer from step 3 and the length-determining method was selected in step 2 into the socket.

Step 4B:
Read the buffer from the socket, stopping when the terminating condition chosen in step 2 is met. If looking for an end of string marker or a count of strings, you will have to read and buffer, then convert byte by byte, reading and buffering more as required. If you sent the size of the encoded string, you can read and buffer the whole string in one shot and then let the decoder loose.

Answer (score 1):

To send a C++ class (which `std::wstring` is an example of) you have to *serialize* it: convert it to the format which can be sent and received. A binary object representation (which you get by taking an address of an object) is not suitable for that purpose.

Luckily, serializing `std::wstring` is not much of a trouble. You just need to access it's character buffer using it's `c_str()` method. The only one thing you need to remeber is that you also need to tell the receiver how long the string is - so that receiver know how much to read.

Comment: That still sends the content byte-wise, which isn't portable.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, for strings it is portable as much as it can be - obviously, EBDIC encoding will fail to be read on ANSI system, but there is not much which can be done here. Barred those extremes, it is portable.

Comment: @SergeyA: I think Ulrich is referring to the fact that `std::wstring` itself is not portable, since `wchar_t` is not the same on all platforms. On Windows, it is 2 bytes in size, usable for UTF-16 encoding.  On other platforms, it is 4 bytes in size, usable for UTF-32 encoding instead.  When you serialize a string, you should pick an encoding that is portable across all platforms that will need to deserialize it.  UTF-8 is most commonly used for that. A UTF-16 `std::wstring` on Windows can be serialized to UTF-8 and then deserialized to a UTF-32 `std::wstring` on a *Nix system, for instance.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, this is of course correct - but this would be somewhat in the viscinity ANSI vs EBCDIC thing I mentioned above. It is feasible that contents of `std::wstring` is not a string at all - it might be a png file buffer for all we know. I thing, those details just detract from the actual task at hand.

Comment: How do I serialize the `std::wstring` properly? I am currently using `char* serial = (char*)wstring.c_str();`, but this only gives me the first character of the `std::wstring`.

Comment: @SergeyA: noone in their right mind would use a `std::wstring` to hold binary data, like a PNG. A `std::string` perhaps, yes.

Comment: @Ben: `wstring.c_str()` would give you a pointer to the `wchar_t` characters, and `wstring.size()` or `wstring.length()` would tell you how many characters are present. If you send that data as-is, you can pass that pointer to `send()` specifying `count * sizeof(wchar_t)` as the byte count. However, as I explained earlier, sending `wchar_t` data as-is is not a good idea, you should convert it to a more portable encoding first, like UTF-8, and then send that instead. There are numerous examples of converting a `std::wstring` to UTF-8.  C++11 even has built-in classes for that exact purpose.

Comment: "C++11 even has built-in classes for that exact purpose" Mother fud! How did I miss that? My life probably just got a lot easier!

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have tried using `wstring.c_str()` in the 'send()' function as the second parameter in order to test it out, but it gives me a compiler error saying that `"const wchar_t*" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char*"`.

Comment: @Ben: you still have to typecast the pointer, you just don't have to convert the string data to another format if you are going to send it as-is (which I strongly advise you NOT to do), eg: `send(clientSocket, (const char*)wstring.c_str(), wstring.size() * sizeof(wchar_t), 0);`